# Remove last entered character from textfield using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me how to remove the last entered character from textfield.

For example I have to allow only integers in the textfield.

so if we enter any hyphen(-) not as first character it should remove.

How can I achieve this using jquery?

I can do it using keypress where i can restrict keycode based on numbers available. But I want to find out the last entered character using keyup.

Comment: If you actually just want integers I can recommend using `type="number"` on your input.

Comment: @smoksnes the number field also allows `+`, `-`, `.` and `e`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes. That's true, and the OP didn't want to use `-`.

Comment: I know all those things but I just want to know is there any way to find out which character is the latest entry in the textfield at what charset

Comment: Just wrote half an answer, and then the post just closed? Why was that? (I'm kinda new to StackOverflow, so just trying to figure it out...)

Comment: @user1268130: You can use `textbox.value[textbox.value.length - 1]` to get the last character in the textbox.

Comment: That provides the last value even though if we enter any character at first. In that situation how can I get the latest entry